# Laptop is locking itself randomly only when is pulgged

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, sleep, hibernate

i have a Dell Inspiron 17 7000 Series 7746, and recently i change my battery because it was old(aprox 5 years)and didn't stay charged more than 10 min,so i took my laptop to a local pc service and have it changed.The battery works fine now and has an autonomy around 3~4 hours,BUT if i keep my laptop plugged in,windows 10 will lock automatically in 10~20 min,pretty random,even if i use the laptop or not.When it's not plugged in,the problem doesn't appear.
I have tried a lot of solutions like : 
-in the power options, Sleep - Hibernate after , are set both to "Never"(on battery/plugged in)
-PCI Express - Link State Power Management (on battery :off/ plugged in : off)
-System unattended sleep timeout is set more than 60 min

Comment: Add to your question what you mean by lock.  Do you have to hard restart or are you talking about the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at "Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\**Edit Plan Settings**" you should find the setting your looking for.